# Import excel file into teradata using tpt

Tags: import, teradata

I am required to load an excel file to a teradata table which already has data in it. I have used TPT Inserter operator to load data with CSV files. I am not sure how to directly load an excel file using TPT Inserter. 
When I tried providing the excel file with TextDelimiter='TAB', the parser threw an error

> data_connector: TPT19134 !ERROR! Fatal data error processing file 'd:\sample_dat
>   a.csv'. Delimited Data Parsing error: Too few columns in row 1.

1) Could someone explain what are the options required while directly importing excel file to teradata

2) How to load a TAB delimited file in teradata using tptLoad / tptInserter

the script that I have used is:

```
define job insert_data
description 'Load from Excel to TD table'
(
define operator insert_operator
type inserter
schema *
attributes
(
 varchar logonmech='LDAP',
 varchar username='username',
 varchar userpassword='password',
 varchar tdpid='tdpid',
 varchar targettable='excel_to_table'
);
define schema upload_schema
(
 quarter varchar(20),
 cust_type varchar(20)
);
define operator data_connector
type dataconnector producer
schema upload_schema
attributes
(
 varchar filename='d:\sample_data.xlsx',
 varchar format='delimited',
 varchar textdelimiter='TAB',
 varchar openmode='Read'
);
apply ('insert into excel_to_table(quarter, cust_type) values(:quarter, :cust_type);')
to operator (insert_operator[1])
select quarter, cust_type
from operator (data_connector[1]); 
);
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure the file is in Tab delimited format? .xlsx extension generally isn't tab delimited. Have you verified the contents of the file by opening it in a text editor like Notepad++?

Comment: @xenodevil you are right. I opened the xlsx file in notepad and found only garbage data. That should be the reason for TPT error. wondering is there any way that we can load excel data directly to Teradata using TPT?...

Comment: No, there isn't any generic way to loading random Excel files into TD using native Teradata Utilities. The reason, I think, is that the Excel files can contain complex objects (graphs/charts/images) and formulas which require a complex tool for proper manipulation. You may find some 3rd party tools for such purposes but if its only a single file then it is way easier to manually convert it into CSV format and then load the CSV file using native TTUs

Answer (score 0):

The scripts actually seems fine by the looks besides for the fact the the error is related to delimited data and a .xlsx extension file is specified in the script. Are you sure that the specified file is Tab delimited?

Formats supported by TPT Dataconnector operator are:

- Binary - Binary data fitting exactly in the defined Schema plus indicator bytes
- Delimited - Easier for multiple column human readable files, limited to all varchar schema
- Formatted - For working with data exported by Teradata TTUs
- Text - For text files containing fixed width columns, also human readable, limited to all varchar schema
- Unformatted - For working with data exported by Teradata TTUs

The original excel data (in true xls or xlsx format) is not directly supported by native TPT operators. But if your data is really Tab delimited then this shouldn't be a problem; you should be able to load this. An obvious point to consider in loading a delimited file is that Char or Varchar fields must not contain delimiter within data. You can escape delimiter characters in data by using a '\'. A more subtle point is that you cannot specify TAB delimiter in lower case, i.e. `varchar textdelimiter='TAB'` works but `varchar textdelimiter='tab'` doesn't. Also, any other control characters (besides TAB) cannot be specified as delimiters.

If you truly need to load excel files then you may need to pre-process it into a loadable format such as delimited or binary or text data. You can write separate code in any language to achieve this.